# Showing two informations in tree node

Tags: layout, color-scheme, tree

In my web application I have a tree with each node holding two status.

Nodes are circles linked with each other.

The status can be either OK, KO, or PARTIAL.

The first status is the "technical status" of the node.
The second status is the "functional status".

The functional status of the node is dependant of its technical status.

I need a way to show the two status (OK/KO/PARTIAL) in a way that users can quickly identify which nodes are in KO or PARTIAL functional or technical status.

Comment: An image would help or quick sketch would help (you can use balsamiq right here in UX stack exchange)

Comment: Any design implications for this sentence? "The functional status of the node is dependant of its technical status."

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking having the functional status as a colored circle red for KO , orange for Partial , green for Ok and a border around the circle to show the tehnical status with the same system status colors.